# XSL, display item[1] and item[2] in same html-table

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting

I want to display XML content in a HTML table. I use the following (simplified) code to do so:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/products/product">
        <xsl:sort select="populariteit" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

With the following (simplified) XML:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <title>Title One</title>
        <popularity>250</popularity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <title>Title Two</title>
        <popularity>500</popularity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <title>Title Three</title>
        <popularity>400</popularity>
    </product>
</products>
```

What it does is sort the list by 'popularity', and then display the title from the first entry in the table (the most popular).

Now, what I want to accomplish is to display the titles from the *first two* popular items. But whatever I try, the XSLT outputs them in *two different tables instead of one*.

I've tried things like:

```
<xsl:template match="product">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="position()=2">
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

But that results in two different tables; I want the titles to be displayed next to each other in the same table, *while also still using the info from the sorted list*.

My desired HTML output would be:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Title Three Title Two
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It's important I use only use one XSL to generate this output, because of certain limitations in the software I'm using.

Comment: Please post the desired HTML output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you will need to put the code generating the table in another template e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/products/product">
        <xsl:sort select="populariteit" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
      </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 3">

                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </td>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

That puts each title in a cell of its own, if you want all in one cell you would need to move the `td` result element up to the other template as well and only output titles in the template for `product`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using a template like this? More like my example? My table may need to get data from (a lot) more different XML-items in the future.

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal, Your current question is completely answered. Please *accept* this question and ask a new question about your further problems. Never let the readers *guess* what you want -- by saying "My table may need to get data from (a lot) more different XML-items in the future".

Comment: Jeffrey, if you want one table only you can't map each product element to a new table, as a template matching `product` and creating a result `table` for each would do. If you have further requirements I agree with Dimitre that you should ask them in a new question where you provide representative samples of input and wanted output.